# Is it normal now for convection to cycle on and off?

Tags: oven, convection

I just upgraded from an older (20-year-old KitchenAid) oven to a new medium-high-end one (GE).  In my old oven, when I turned on convection, the fan ran continuously, and it was pretty good for accelerated browning of foods.  I've found that the new oven cycles the convection fan on and off rather than running it continuously -- and at least so far, doesn't seem very effective at convection browning.  This is a bit disappointing considering the cost of the oven.

What little commentary I can find on the internet seems to treat this on/off cycling as normal.  Is it?  Is this how most new convention ovens work?

Comment: Many ovens have different modes, there may be one with fan and top grill, that's great for rapid browning.

Comment: Yeah, this one has "convection roast" which I'm going to try next.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the modern oven only uses the fan when actively heating up the interior or when the heat is not equally distributed anymore. That way it would save some electricity.

If that's the case, then allowing some heat to escape, eg by slightly opening the oven door in certain intervals, could provide your desired effect.

Alternatively it's worth it to try using your new oven at a higher temperature. It is possible that the thermometer of your old oven was less accurate or the convection wasn't working as well, so that the browning happened due to locally elevated temperatures.

Comment: Really, the way the old oven worked is "convection == fan on continuously".  Personally, I believe that's the way convection *should* work, and if I wanna save power that should be up to me, not the stove.  Anyway, if you modify your answer to say clearly "yes, that's the new normal" with maybe a link I can pick it as the answer.